# OpenGL: Increasing the number of the lines changes the antialiasing?

Tags: delphi, opengl, delphi-2010

I am writing a paint program in Delphi. The user clicks 2 points on the screen and a line is drawn between them. I want the lines to be anti-aliased. I put this code in create() procedure of the OpenGL class (which is called just 1 time in the start):

```
 glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
 glEnable(GL_BLEND);
 glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
 glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
```

When I start drawing, the first, second and maybe the third lines are drawn fine. But interestingly enough, when the number of the lines increases (say 7, 8 lines), the anti-aliasing starts to fail! By adding each line on the screen, it just gets worse and the lines edges starts to become like sawtooth!!

I also put the same code on the top of my draw() procedure which draws the lines (and runs by each click of the mouse), but nothing changes.

Am I doing something wrong here? Anybody has any suggestion?

Comment: Do the jaggies seem to be angle dependent?  Lines near horizontal or vertical generally get less fuzzy than those in between.

Comment: No. That isn't the case. It doesn't differ what is the angle or the length of the line is.

Comment: Any chance you can post a screenshot?

Comment: Here are the screenshots: first one with just 2 lines and the second with many lines drawn. I think the difference is visible?
2 Line: http://bit.ly/9EBrg6
Many Lines: http://bit.ly/9gEMHo

Comment: The compression artifacts in those JPEGs are obscuring the problem, try PNG.

Comment: OK. Here are the PNG ones:
2 Lines: http://bit.ly/byTcxx
Many Lines: http://bit.ly/cKQah2

Comment: The red rectangles are also missing antialiasing starting from the fifth rectangle. Are you sure that there isn't any code between those 4 lines and line drawing that could change the blending settings? Move those 4 lines of code as close to the line drawing as possible.

Create a test case to draw 100 lines without mouse interaction. Does that fail too?

Comment: I am totally confused here. The lines are drawn in a FOR loop and every time I click the mouse, a line is added to an array and that array is passes to OpenGL to draw all the lines in it. Everything is the same for all the lines. Why should it change when the number increases?

Comment: Please note that lines antialiasing fully fupported only with professional GPUs like nVidia Quadro, or AMD FireGL. So behavior on other GPU can be different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are You sure You're not drawing any line segment more than once? Do You call `glClear` before doing any drawing?

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! It was exactly the problem. I was drawing each line more than once and that caused the effect.

Answer (score 2):

[Check](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml) the value of `GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE` and compare it against the [`glLineWidth()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLineWidth.xml)s you're trying to use.

Comment: Good answer--I had assumed they were all the same width, but he didn't say that explicitly.

Comment: Upon further re-reading I'm not sure where I got the idea either :(

Comment: Are you sure standard OpenGL has GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE as a constant? Because it doesn't recognize it in Delphi (using standard OpenGL.dll).

BTW, I am using 3 in the glLineWidth() and I even checked with 1 and get the same problem.

Comment: I added the screenshots in the comment above.